# Can typeahead.js make cross domain requests?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsonp, typeahead

[Typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) is a very popular autosuggestion library from Twitter.

I just installed and it does not seem to support cross domain requests via JSONP. 
I get the error about remote origin not allowed.

I have googled around and I can't find anything related to it.

Can anyone confirm if this functionality is supported or not.

Comment: Typeahead itself cannot "support" / overrule Same-origin policy / Access-Control-Allow-Origin issues - it is totally up to the browser. If you want a cross domain request as source to the typeahead, then you must deal with this as you do when are dealing with that challenge in any other context.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding your first issue, judging by your error message, you may not have implemented it correctly because typeahead is not executing a JSONP request.

**As of Typeahead.js v0.9.3** you can execute a JSONP request by passing 'jsonp' as the dataType, like this:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'jsonpExample',
  remote: {
    // ...
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  }
});
```

You'll find that typeahead will now execute JSONP requests.

**UPDATE**

In answering your second issue. The author has targeted to support JSONP - and by and large it does work - but it doesn't work properly in some edge cases in the current version.

For instance, if you need to trigger an JSONP request using a query other than "callback", you're going to be stuck. In this or a similar situation, you have two options:

1) Patch typeahead.js yourself to get JSONP working. The callback name issue, for instance, [can be fixed by a simple solution](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/417)

2) Wait for v0.10 to be released when the full jQuery AJAX object is exposed. Unfortunately it's a month past its promised delivery date and there are no indications it will be finished in the coming weeks

Answer (score 2):

With 0.10.5, it works over remote servers. On top of C Blanchard's answer, I needed `jsonp` attribute in `ajax`.

```
var items = new Bloodhound({
  ...
  remote: {
    url: 'http://localhost/api/items?q=%QUERY',
    ajax: {
      jsonp: 'callback',
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    }
});
items.initialize()
...
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  ...
  source: items.ttAdapter()
});
```